# React Filters not updating properly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

I'm building a filtering functionality for my React site. The site displays a list of stores, and I want to let the user filter the list by country of the store and if the store accepts payments in cash.

To accomplish that I have a `state` called `stores` that contain the original array of stores.
There is another `state` called `filteredStores` that starts with all the stores in `stores`

When the user selects one country from the list. the app replaces the `filteredStores` array with a new array containing only the stores for the selected country and display that on the screen.
The user can check a `checkbox` called **Accepts cash payment** to display only the stores that take cash payments, for this filter I have a `state` called `acceptCash`

The user should be able to use either filter or both.

```
  const { countryFiltering, setCountryFiltering } = useContext(countryFilteringContext);
  const { acceptCashFiltering, setAcceptCashFiltering } = useContext(acceptCashFilteringContext);

// ****** Run filterStores every time the state of countryFiltering or acceptCashFiltering changes ****** 

  useEffect(() => {
    filterStores();
  }, [countryFiltering]);

  useEffect(() => {
    filterStores();
  }, [acceptCashFiltering]);

  // ****** COUNTRY FILTER ****** ****** COUNTRY FILTER ****** ****** COUNTRY FILTER ****** 

  const countryFilter = (value) => {
    if (countryFiltering.indexOf(value) === -1) {
      setCountryFiltering([...countryFiltering, value])
      setCountrySearch('');
    }
    else {
      const array = countryFiltering.filter(country => country != value);
      setCountryFiltering(array);
      setCountrySearch('');
    }
  }

// ****** OPTIONS FILTER ****** ****** OPTIONS FILTER ****** ****** OPTIONS FILTER ****** 

  const optionsFilter = (filter, value) => {
    if (filter === 'cash') {
      if (!acceptCashFiltering) {
        setAcceptCashFiltering(value);
      } else {
        setAcceptCashFiltering('');
      }
    }
  }

  // ****** FILTER STORES ****** ****** FILTER STORES ****** ****** FILTER STORES ****** 

  const filterStores = () => {
    setFilteredStores(stores);
    if (countryFiltering) {
      var array = [];
      countryFiltering.map((country) => {
        const countries = stores.filter(store => store.storeFields.identity.location.country === country);
        countries.map(country => array = [...array, country]);
        setFilteredStores(array);
      });
    };
    if (acceptCashFiltering === 'Yes') {
      var array = [];
      array = filteredStores.filter(store => store.storeFields.storeRequirements.acceptCash === 'Yes');
      setFilteredStores(array);
    }
  }
// ****** END ****** ****** END ****** ****** END ****** 

return (
<div>
   <div key={countryArray.indexOf(country)}>
     <div onClick={() => { countryFilter(country) }} >{country}</div>
   </div>
   <div>
     <label htmlFor='cash'>Accept Cash Payments</label>
     <input type='checkbox' value='Yes' id='cash' onChange={(e) => { optionsFilter('cash', e.target.value) }} />
   </div>
</div>

)
```

When I select a country, let's say Australia, and the a check **Accepts Cash**, it shows the right filtered stores. If I uncheck **Accept Cash** it shows all the stores from Australia correctly with out applying the second filter. The issue is that if I have a country and **Accept Cash** selected and then I want to deselect the country, the `filteredStores` state is not getting updating so it keeps showing the stores from the previously selected country. If I uncheck **Accept Cash** then the states updates and all the stores show again.

The `filterStores()` function should reset the `filteredStores` state to the original `stores` state when it starts running, but it seems as if it is not doing it, not sure why. Any idea why the `filteredStores` array is not getting updated when the **Accept Cash** filter is checked?

Answer (score 0):

You're running into an issue with deep vs shallow cloning of arrays.

Try replacing `setFilteredArray(array)` with `setFilteredArray([...array])`

Also a rather ugly, but quite effective alternative if you don't like destructuring would be `setState(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(array)))`

An explanation of why this causes issues for react state [can be seen here.](https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/setstate-not-working-shallow-copy-vs-deep-copy-lodash-55a015db80ff#:%7E:text=Shallow%20vs%20Deep%20Copies,top%20level%20of%20the%20object.)

Comment: I still don't get it. You mean make the changes in ```setFilteredStores(array)```
inside the ```if``` statements in the ```filterStores``` function?

Comment: @CarlosG anywhere there is an array being held in state, needs the change when `setState` is called. Also I'm not sure what `countries.map(country => array = [...array, country]);` is doing. You aren't storing that anywhere and `map` returns a new array. It doesn't mutate the existing one.